# How to fix Wordpress dashboard screen option & help button, it's not working

Tags: dashboard

In my Wordpress dashboard "Screen Option" and "Help" button are not pulldown.

[image: Screen Option not working]

Could anybody help me to solve the problem.
Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like Javascript is not loading. Do you have Javascript turned off or is it blocked by an ad blocking browser extension?

Comment: Changing browser may help you. :)

Comment: Thanks, I tried with desable ad blocking ext and also tried with ohter browers, but same result. sorry.

Comment: Hello Musfeq - Welcome to the WordPress development community! While your Javascript may be loading there may be other conflicts arising. Do you know when these items stopped functioning/if any updates or changes were made immediately before then? The first step in troubleshooting this problem is open your browser's Javascript console (`Ctrl` + `Shift` + `i` and then the "Console" tab in Google Chrome) and look for errors (Red messages denoted with a red circle with a white 'x', in Chrome's console). These errors will hopefully give us a better idea of what's going on.

Answer (score 9):

Check if you or a plugin include bootstrap and the bootstrap CSS / Theme files.

Bootstraps `.hidden` class looks like:

```
.hidden {
  display: none !important;
}
```

But overrides wordpress' definition of `.hidden`:

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

The Top 'Help' & 'Screen Options' bars are displayed via inline style `display: block`, which is overridden by bootstraps `.hidden {display: none !important}` css class.

This can be fixed by rewriting the Top Bars Css via Jquery / JS.

Working example:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $("#contextual-help-link").click(function () {
        $("#contextual-help-wrap").css("cssText", "display: block !important;");
    });
    $("#show-settings-link").click(function () {
        $("#screen-options-wrap").css("cssText", "display: block !important;");
    });
})
```

Wordpress Version 4.5.2

Bootstrap: 3.3.6

Comment: Spot on! I am using wordpress veresion 5.0.3 with bs 3.3.7. The screen options and help did not work. However, with your solutions the div jumps out instead of slide out.

Answer (score 4):

I solve this problem after hours of searching. AdBlock hiding this tab in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the webpage select `inspect element`. Then select console. Check if gives any error which says jQuery is missing. In my case jQuery files were missing in WordPress migration which I had to add myself.

Answer (score -1):

It's a jQuery problem. I solved it by adding: `define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false);` to the `wp-config.php` file, just below the `define('DB_HOST')` line.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Disable_Javascript_Concatenation

Comment: While this solution may alleviate the symptom, the underlying conflicts/errors are likely still present.