# Screen Options & Help Buttons not working when including Bootstrap Css

Tags: wp-admin, twitter-bootstrap

The wordpress 'Help' and 'Screen Options' Buttons in the wordpress Admin Panels are not working when including bootstrap and specifically the bootstrap-css files.

It is caused because bootstraps css overides:

```
.hidden {
  display: none !important;
}
```

How can I make the buttons working again?

It is related to [this Thread](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/127179/how-to-fix-wordpress-dashboard-screen-option-help-button-its-not-working/) but it is not linked to bootstrap therefore I answer it here again as a bootstrap specific problem.

Comment: I also had the same issue. The reason was I had installed a PopUP plugin, so I deactivated it and it works fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you or a plugin include bootstrap and the bootstrap CSS / Theme files.

Bootstraps `.hidden` class looks like:

```
.hidden {
  display: none !important;
}
```

But overrides wordpress' definition of `.hidden`:

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

The Top 'Help' & 'Screen Options' bars are displayed via inline style `display: block`, which is overridden by bootstraps `.hidden {display: none !important}` css class.

This can be fixed by rewriting the Top Bars Css via Jquery / JS.

Working example:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $("#contextual-help-link").click(function () {
        $("#contextual-help-wrap").css("cssText", "display: block !important;");
    });
    $("#show-settings-link").click(function () {
        $("#screen-options-wrap").css("cssText", "display: block !important;");
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Add this in the CSS:

```
* {
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

Comment: Please add some text explaining why this should work.